# c# Replace transparent area from image with a color

Tags: c#, alpha-transparency

I receive an image from a Flutter mobile app like this (base64):
https://next-at-ms.com/base64data.txt
back to image is something like this:
https://next-at-ms.com/imagedata.bmp

i need to include this image in a Fastreport.NET pdf report but it appear like a full dark image

as far as i understood it is an image/bmp type

Following other questions similar here, i try looping pixel by pixel, i removed alpha channel, i try a suggestion based on PdfSharp / Bitmapsources /BmpDitmapDecoder and combinations of them;
i tried the accepted and even other answers with no luck.

I noticed that opening the file in windows explorer the image looks like full dark while in OSX preview I see the transparent image correctly same as in Chrome Browser in both operating systems

Any idea?

Comment: The bitmap has a broken BMP header, its height is negative.  The .NET codec seems to work around it by generating a 24 bpp from the data.  No alpha, that's why everything looks black.  Not an uncommon bug in apps that use the equivalent of Bitmap.LockBits(), it generates a negative height when the scanlines are in the reverse order.  Best to file a bug with the owner/author of that app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color with [SixLabors.ImageSharp](https://docs.sixlabors.com/index.html)

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
...

var b64Img = "your-base64-image-string";
var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Img);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var image = Image.Load(imageBytes))
    {
        image.Mutate(x => x.BackgroundColor(Color.White));
        image.SaveAsJpeg(ms);
    }
    var b64White = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```